# An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I'm trying to use this query in my jpa but it doesn't work:

```
List<Object[]> query = em.createQuery("SELECT Tstat.idStatistiques, TL.codeLieu, TL.materiel, TL.zone, sum(Tstat.colis) as colis, Tstat.defaut, sum(Tstat.nbreDefaut) as nbreDefaut,"
                    + " sum(Tstat.nonLu) as nonLu, sum(Tstat.multiple) as multiple, sum(Tstat.nonRecu) as nonRecu, sum(Tstat.incoherent) as incoherent, sum(Tstat.requete) as requete , "
                    + "sum(Tstat.tempsFonctionnement) as tempsFonctionnement, SUM(Tstat.tempsUtilisation) as tempsUtilisation, Tstat.modeFonctionnement FROM "
+ "( SELECT CURRENT_DATE as horodatage, St.idStatistiques, St.colis, St.defaut, St.nbreDefaut, St.nonLu, St.requete, St.multiple, St.nonRecu, St.incoherent, St.tempsFonctionnement, St.tempsUtilisation, St.modeFonctionnement FROM Statistique St )"                  
                    + " UNION "                     
+ "(SELECT h.horodatage, h.idStatistiques, h.colis, h.defaut, h.nbreDefaut, h.nonLu, h.nonRecu, h.requete, h.multiple, h.incoherent, h.tempsFonctionnement, h.tempsUtilisation, h.modeFonctionnement FROM Statistiqueshisto h )"
                    + " Tstat "
                    + "LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Lieux) as TL on Tstat.idStatistiques = TL.code_VI WHERE idStatistiques like :A  ").setParameter("A", 0040+"%").getResultList();
```

This gives me error

> The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL
>   grammar.

Comment: so make it follow JPQL then. "SELECT *" doesnt exist in JPQL as a starter! UNION doesnt exist either. JOIN to a subquery doesnt exist either.

Comment: For select * i totally agree. I was focusing on previous part.
for UNION i'm using eclipseLink wich accept it as explained here:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/j_union.htm